# Maxima - differentiating a piecewise function

Tags: maxima, piecewise, differentiation

Suppose you have a function defined by intervals, such as

```
f(x):=block(if x<0 then x^2 else x^3);
```

When we differentiate it with

```
diff(f(x),x);
```

we get

```
d/dx (if x<0 then x^2 else x^3)
```

whereas I'd like to get

```
(if x<0 then 2*x else 3*x^2)
```

Is there a way to obtain such result?

Answer (score 3):

This may help in a simple case:

```
(%i1) f(x):= charfun(x<0)*x^2 + charfun(x>=0)*x^3$

(%i2) gradef(charfun(y), 0)$

(%i3) diff(f(x),x);
                                           2
(%o3)              2 x charfun(x < 0) + 3 x  charfun(x >= 0)
```

[charfun](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/en/maxima_11.html#IDX482), [gradef](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/en/maxima_18.html#IDX819)

You can try also [Pw.mac](http://sourceforge.net/projects/piecewisefunc/) package from Richard Hennessy.

Comment: This is a nice workaround. Is there any reason to write `gradef(charfun(y),0)` instead of `gradef(charfun(x),0)`?

Comment: It is dummy variable. Should be no difference between `x' and `y'.

Comment: Shouldn't there be some delta functions in the result also?

Comment: It should. But the discontinuities are also missing from the desired
output in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different approach using a simplification rule for "if" expressions. The unsolved part here is to detect discontinuities and generate delta functions for those locations. If you want to ignore those, you can define `FOO` to return 0. Note that I didn't attempt to implement the function `discontinuities`; that part is unsolved here. I can give it a try if there is interest.

```
(%i1) display2d : false $
(%i2) matchdeclare ([aa, bb, cc], all, xx, symbolp) $
(%i3) 'diff (if aa then bb else cc, xx) $
(%i4) tellsimpafter (''%, apply ("if", [aa, diff (bb, xx), true, diff (cc, xx)]) + FOO (aa, bb, cc, xx)) $
(%i5) FOO (a, b, c, x) := 'lsum ((ev (c, x = d) - ev (b, x = d)) * delta (d, x), d, discontinuities (a, x)) $
(%i6) diff (if x > 0 then x^2 else x^3, x);
(%o6) (if x > 0 then 2*x else 3*x^2)+'lsum((d^3-d^2)*delta(d,x),d,
                                           discontinuities(x > 0,x))
```

Comment: I am trying to use it for nested ifs. But this `diff( (if x>1 then (if x>2 then 0 else 1) else 2), x);` gives `(if x > 1 then 'diff(if x > 2 then 0 else 1,x,1) else 0)
 +'lsum(delta(d,x)*(2-(if d > 2 then 0 else 1)),d,discontinuities(x > 1,x))`.

Comment: @slitvinov Yes, `expand(%, 0, 0)` causes a resimplification so the rule is applied to the inner `if`. Try `tellsimp` instead of `tellsimpafter` -- `tellsimp` constructs a function which will apply the simplification rule recursively, while `tellsimpafter` constructs a function which refuses to apply the rule recursively (via the special variable `*AFTERFLAG`). It is certainly regrettable and unfortunate that there is this subtle, incomprehensible difference.

Answer (score 0):

Building on slitinov's answer I wrote this quite naive implementation for functions with more than two "pieces":

```
gradef(charfun(dummy),0)$

/* piecewise function definition */
itv: [[x<0],[x>=0,x<1], [x>=1]]; /* intervals */
fi:  [ 1,    x^2+1,      2*x  ]; /* local functions */

/* creation of global function f and its derivative df */
f:0;
for i: 1 thru 3 do f:f+charfun(apply("and",itv[i]))*fi[i];
df:diff(f,x);

/* display of local functions and derivatives */
for i: 1 thru 3 do (
  apply(assume,itv[i]),
  newline(),
  print(itv[i]),
  print("f = ",ev(f)),
  print("df = ",ev(df)),
  apply(forget,itv[i])
  );

plot2d([f,df],[x,-2,3],[y,-1,5],[style,[lines,4,3],[lines,2,2]]);
```