# Maxima - function definition (define statement)

Tags: function, maxima

Starting from the following Maxima code taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35353946/694360)

```
/* piecewise function definition */
itvs: [[x<0],[x>=0,x<1], [x>=1]]; /* intervals */
pfun:  [ a,    x^2+b,      c*x  ]; /* local functions */

/* piecewise function constructor */
f:0$
for i: 1 thru 3 do f:f+charfun(apply("and",itvs[i]))*pfun[i]$
f;

/* differentiation of piecewise function */
gradef(charfun(dummy),0)$
diff(f,x);
```

I'd like to make a function able to take 2 arguments like `itvs`and `pfun` and return a piecewise function like `f`, but I was not able to do it because of errors due to evaluation of symbols. For example in the following try I get the error "incorrect syntax: itvs is not an infix operator":

```
define(pfc(itvs,pfun),(
    f:0,
    for i: 1 thru length(itvs) do f:f+charfun("and" itvs[i])*pfun[i],
    f
));
```

How can I define such a function?
The documentation I found is very concise and could not help me, is there some less known documentation about this subject?

**EDIT**

An alternative format of input argument, maybe simpler and more flexible, could be:

```
/* piecewise function definition */
pfd: [
    [a,     x<0],
    [x^2+b, x>=0 and x<1],
    [c*x,   x>=1]
];
```

Writing a function constructor with this argument might be simpler.

**FOLLOW UP**

If you don't actually need a piecewise *function* since a piecewise *expression* is enough (as -- I discovered later -- in my case), writing a piecewise expression constructor (using the alternative format of input argument) becomes straightforward:

```
/* pec=piecewise expression constructor */
/* argument is an array of [expression,interval] couples */
pec(x) := sum(x[i][1]*charfun(x[i][2]), i,1,length(x));

f: pec( [[(1+x)/2, x>=-1 and x<1],[3, x<-1 or x>=1]] )

(f)   3*charfun(x<-1 or x>=1)+((x+1)*charfun(x>=-1 and x<1))/2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP indicates that they want `pfc` to construct a piecewise function. Here is an attempt:

```
pfc (itvs, pfun) := block ([body],
    body : sum (charfun (apply ("and", itvs[i]))*pfun[i], i, 1, length(itvs)),
    buildq ([body], lambda ([x], body)));
```

Now `pfc` takes intervals and expressions and constructs an unnamed function of one argument. It's assumed the argument is named `x`; I guess if one wanted to make this a little more complicated, one could specify a different variable as an argument for `pfc` and make it another variable for `buildq`, e.g. `buildq([body, var], lambda([var], body)`.

Comment: It works, thanks! Changing the format of argument (as in my question EDIT) `pfc` becomes even simpler: `pfc (x) := buildq ([body:sum( x[i][1]*charfun(x[i][2]), i, 1, length(x))], lambda ([x], body));`. You might want to add this simpler version to your answer to give it more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things. (1) Instead of `charfun("and" itvs[i])` you want `charfun(apply("and", itvs[i]))`. (2) Instead of `pfc(itvs,pfun)` you want `pfc(x)`. Also (3) probably you want to make `f` a local variable.

I think this might work:

```
define(pfc(x), block([f:0],
    for i: 1 thru length(itvs)
        do f:f+charfun(apply("and", itvs[i]))*pfun[i],
    f));
```

Comment: This works, but not in the sense I wanted. Infact I'd like such function to be a constructor, in the sense that the piecewise (mathematic) function returned should be "defined" by the arguments I pass to `pfc` function. Each time I pass different arguments a different piecewise (mathematic) function should be returned.

Comment: @mmj OK. I'll put a separate answer to address that.